# Can internal classes be accessed within other namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, assemblies

I'm currently reading this book online:
http://www.angelfire.com/theforce/chewy0/csharp/Thinking_in_C-Sharp_.pdf

On page 23 (38 of the PDF document) it states that **internal** classes cannot be accessed from classes within external *namespaces*.

However, in the online Microsoft documentation it states that **internal** classes are only accessible from the same *assembly*.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

From my understanding, an *assembly* can contain classes from multiple *namespaces*. 
Would this not mean from the Microsoft documentation that **internal** classes could be accessed across different *namespaces*?

Or is it true to say that **internal** classes are private within both of their respected *assemblies* and *namespaces*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is the excerpt, right?

> Java uses five explicit keywords to set the boundaries in a class: public,
>   private, protected, internal, and protected internal. Their use and
>   meaning are quite straightforward. These access specifiers determine who
>   can use the definitions that follow. public means the following
>   definitions are available to everyone. The private keyword, on the other
>   hand, means that no one can access those definitions except you, the
>   creator of the type, inside member functions of that type. private is a
>   brick wall between you and the client programmer. If someone tries to
>   access a private member, they’ll get a compile-time error. protected
>   acts like private, with the exception that an inheriting class has access to
>   protected members, but not private members. Inheritance will be
>   introduced shortly. internal is often called “friendly”–the definition can
>   be accessed by other classes in the same namespace as if it were public,
>   but is not accessible to classes in different namespaces. Namespaces will
>   be discussed in depth in chapter #ref# [sic]. protected internal allows
>   access by classes within the same namespace (as with internal) or by
>   inheriting classes (as with protected) even if the inheriting classes are
>   not within the same namespace.
>
> C#’s default access, which comes into play if you don’t use one of the
>   aforementioned specifiers, is internal

The author is probably conflating Java's `internal` with c#'s `internal`.

They are slightly different, because Java does not have assemblies; it has packages, which organize classes into namespaces.

In c#, namespace has absolutely no relationship with accessibility modifiers. Only classes within the same assembly can access an `internal` type or member, unless you use the [InternalsVisibleTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute. Namespace doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easiest way to answer this was to test it-
So I've made 2 namespaces within 1 assembly, and accessed an internal variable.

Short answer- the Microsoft documentation is correct- it's possible to access an internal variable within the same assembly, even when you have 2 different namesapces.

Here's the code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
        internal string thing;
        public Class1()
        {
            thing = "original data";
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Class2
    {
        public ConsoleApplication1.Class1 class1= new ConsoleApplication1.Class1();
        public Class2()
        {
            class1.thing = "other namespace modification";
        }
    }
}
```

When calling Class2 constructor, the modified data was displayed.

```
var class2 = new ConsoleApplication2.Class2();
Console.WriteLine(class2.class1.thing);
```

Result:

```
"other namespace modification"
```

Hope this helps :)